# Show that the following iteration rule fulfills the condition of the Banach-fixed-point theorem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Given the following system of differential equations:

$$\dot{\textbf{v}} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -800.2 & -399.6 \\
 -399.6 & -200.8 \\
\end{array}
\right) \textbf{y} - \textbf{c}$$

Show that the forward and backward Euler method given by $\textbf{y}_{n+1} = \textbf{y}_n + h(\textbf{Ay}_n-c)$ and $\textbf{y}_{n+1} = \textbf{y}_n + h(\textbf{Ay}_{n+1}-c)$ fulfill the conditions of the Banach-fixed-point theorem, i.e. that there exists $L<1 : \|\textbf{y}_{n+1}^{(1)}-\textbf{y}_{n+1}^{(2)}\|_2 \leq L \| \textbf{y}_n^{(1)}-\textbf{y}_n^{(2)}\|_2$.

Now this is my try for the forward euler method:

Let $y_{n}^{(1)}, y_{n}^{(2)} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be two random vectors in the n-th iteration.

$$\|\textbf{y}_{n+1}^{(1)}-\textbf{y}_{n+1}^{(2)} \|_2 = \|\textbf{y}_n^{(1)} + h(\textbf{Ay}_n^{(1)}-\textbf{c})-\textbf{y}_n^{(2)}-h(\textbf{Ay}_n^{(2)}-\textbf{c})\|_2 $$
$$\leq \| \textbf{y}_n^{(1)}-\textbf{y}_n^{(2)}\|_2 + h\|A\|_2 \| \textbf{y}_n^{(1)}-\textbf{y}_n^{(2)}\|_2 = \| \textbf{y}_n^{(1)}-\textbf{y}_n^{(2)}\|_2(1+h\|\textbf{A}\|_2)$$

Obviously there is no way for $1+h\|\textbf{A} \|_2$ to be less than 1 for $h>0$.

Can someone please tell me where I did something wrong in the derivation of the inequality and whether I actually took the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never actually solved this kind of problem before, so please think critically, but I believe your problem is that you are using the triangle inequality too much:

Consider

\begin{align*}
\Vert\textbf{y}_{n+1}^{(1)}-\textbf{y}_{n+1}^{(2)} \rVert \leq \lVert \textbf{y}_{n}^{(1)}-\textbf{y}_{n}^{(2)}\rVert\lVert I +hA\rVert
\end{align*}

Now, since $A$ is a symmetric matrix with distinct eigenvalues, it is orthogonally diagonalizable, therefore, write

\begin{align*}
 \lVert I +hA\rVert = \lVert PP^{-1} +hPDP^{-1}\rVert = \lVert I +hD\rVert
\end{align*}
where $P$ is the matrix of eigenvectors with length $1$ and $D$ is the diagonal matrix of elements $-1000$ and $-1$. It is clear that if $h< 1/1000$ you will have a contractive mapping.

It is worth noting that this small $h$ is to be expected due to the extremely large ratio between the largest and smallest eigenvalue in absolute value. If you consider the *homogeneous equation*, the analytic solution to the differential equation is spanned by $\{e^{-1000t}\mathbf{x}_{1},e^{-t}\mathbf{x}_{2}\}$ where $\mathbf{x}_{1}$ and $\mathbf{x}_{2}$ are the eigenvectors of $A$. Note that the exponential decay of the second solution is more than a thousandfold slower and even for small $t$, the first term is negligible.

However, if you instead examine the behavior of Euler's method in the homogeneous case, you can recursively define $y_{n}$ and get

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{y}_{n+1} = (I+hA)^{n}\mathbf{y}_{0} = P(I+hD)P^{-1}\mathbf{y}_{0}
\end{align*}

and so

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{y}_{n+1} = (1-1000h)^{n}\mathbf{x}_{1} + (1-h)^{n}\mathbf{x}_{2}
\end{align*}

that is, unless $h$ is extremely small, the first term is going to blow up geometrically instead of qualitatively matching the asymptotics of the true solution

Comment: It works. h = 1/1000 is definitely the point at which the solution begins to converge. Thanks a lot for your answer, I appreciate it very much.